# Yii user authentication and session not working

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I am building a website in Yii and I am stuck at the user authentication step. Whatever i do I am not able to authenticate users or store some value in the session.

My UserIdentity component is as follows:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate(){
        if(($userRecord = Admin::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username)))===null){
            return $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        }
        if($userRecord->password!=hash('sha256', $this->password)){
            return $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
        $this->_id=$userRecord->id;
        $this->setState('title', $userRecord->username);
        Yii::app()->session['clientId'] = $userRecord->clientId;
        Yii::app()->session['id'] = $userRecord->id;
        Yii::app()->session['loggedin'] = true;

        return $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->_id;
    }

}
```

My `Yii:app()->user->isGuest` always returns true and `Yii::app()->user->id` returns nothing.

That is why I tried using `Yii::app()->session['loggedin']` to do authentication. But even that is not working. When I access session array like this `Yii::app()->session` I get the error `Property "CWebUser.session" is not defined.`.

This is getting really frustrating. I am new to Yii. Please help.

Comment: did you [login](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail) the user?

Comment: Oh sh1t. I had commented out the login function from the model while testing. Thank you. It now works perfectly.

Comment: great i have added it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`login`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail) function of CWebUser.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#login-and-logout).